# connecting wget to vpn

Tags: wget, vpn

I'm trying to download some files using wget but the problem is the files will only download from specific servers how can I use wget over VPN?
p s: I tried use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=[server]:[port] but it didn't work I need to connect to a VPN server not a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Install a VPN on your machine first, then run the command

Answer (score 0):

Proxies and VPNs are entirely different things. The proxy functionality won't be of any use to you here.

To use a VPN you have to setup a connection at the OS level (i assume linux ? but i could be wrong) - the `wget` tool itself wont be involved, you'll just run that after your connection is replaced with the VPN connection (no need for any special flags).

---

As for how you setup the vpn connection, that differs a lot based on the particular details of your situation. It could involve running `openvpn yourinfo.ovpn` or something like that, or your vpn provider may offer a separate application to set up the tunnel connection and then adjust your OS's routing table so traffic flows through the tunnel instead of to the normal gateway.

Comment: I'm using wget in google colab; how can I setup a VPN in colab?

Comment: That's a question for your VPN provider. They must have given you instructions or have something on their website.

Comment: I have host IP and user/pass from my VPN provider; they provided some methods for OpenVPN and AnyConnect but nothing for linux/colab

Comment: i'm not familiar with colab but i think it's just linux right? ifso openvpn should be available

Comment: yes Linux will do fine but I'm a total beginner with Linux can you guide me on how to setup an OpenVPN with Linux?

Comment: No thats a lot of work. You could google for some tutorials, but to be honest if you have no linux experience then setting up vpn tunnels is likely going to be a bit much.